# Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.setAsync is not set

Tags: c#, typescript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am using the office api within outlook. I'm trying to set an additional x-header to my mail in the composer scope, so I can identify the mail later on.
I used this documentation here to create my bits of code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.internetheaders?view=outlook-js-preview

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.setAsync({"x-sap-mail-addin-id": this.state.addinMailId}, { 
  }, (assyRes) => {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.internetHeaders.getAsync(["x-sap-mail-addin-id"], { }, (val) => { 
      console.log(val);
    });
    console.log(assyRes);
});
```

[image: Debug screen on assyRes]
[image: Cheked input variable]
[image: Tracked down the is set to the headers]

As the screens show, the value is set right now.
So I tried to read the mail from the MS Graph (and got it) as follows:

```cs
    var configuration = provider.GetService<ConfigurationService>();
    var clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create(configuration.AzureAD.ApplicationId)
                        .WithTenantId(configuration.AzureAD.TenantId)
                        .WithClientSecret(configuration.AzureAD.AppSecret)
                        .Build();

    var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientApp);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);


    var messageStream = await graphClient.Users["mail2sap-sendmail@gisdev.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages["AAMkADMzNDg3YTFiLWI4NDItNDI5Ni1hNzU1LTE3YmRhYjZkYzFjMwBGAAAAAABc2UL4pp4rRoxnwy3lWAHyBwAmKhkFHv2sRIc0wWWwSW0lAAAAAAEMAAAmKhkFHv2sRIc0wWWwSW0lAAAAAAlEAAA="].Content.Request().GetAsync();
    var messageMetaData = await graphClient.Users["mail2sap-sendmail@gisdev.onmicrosoft.com"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

So I'd have expected the header to be somewhere here:
[image: Resultset image]

But neither the Guid nor the attribute name can be found in the entire message text.
Same is true for the meta data from the graph.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here is what I got from graph:

```
Received: from AM0PR09MB4036.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:208:19f::13)
 by DB8PR09MB4058.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Thu, 6 May 2021
 07:53:21 +0000
Received: from AM9PR09MB4593.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:20b:287::6)
 by AM0PR09MB4036.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com (2603:10a6:208:19f::13) with
 Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
 cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.4108.27; Thu, 6 May
 2021 07:53:21 +0000
Received: from AM9PR09MB4593.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::c008:da09:d9b2:47cc]) by AM9PR09MB4593.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::c008:da09:d9b2:47cc%4]) with mapi id 15.20.4108.026; Thu, 6 May 2021
 07:53:20 +0000
From: User <User@tenant.onmicrosoft.com>
To: User <User@tenant.onmicrosoft.com>
Subject: 123
Thread-Topic: 123
Thread-Index: AQHXQkdWc7SsFNH9wEqedVXYoSRrXQ==
Date: Thu, 6 May 2021 07:53:20 +0000
Message-ID:
  <LONGID@AM9PR09MB4593.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: en-DE, en-GB, en-US, de-DE
Content-Language: aa
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: AM9PR09MB4593.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
  MESSAGE_ID
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-RecordReviewCfmType: 0
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
  ucf:0;jmr:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(750129)(520011016)(706158)(944506458)(944626604);
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
  didRz2nSjLEkd9U7ivulQq20MhG39bFkrSpiT//1gM51su3XDIz+haWsUqAYbfT7XVFmv7/sHNnDbS9pAvqN3lt8juTcmd4kiXLclZf6HsXGy9aBC5BbqSN5dgq5rTQ+1vjMZS6dlbbVvEb96d9B9BkOCTdYexnWDW6y4BQjwqAMthoSs3a9Dlr3TOy9ijC6DltkRQOt9lqQqtPViwoPqLnpF42EC5Lk98xKvWHHomRTcW3tcTL05mpAgvH5bLGZvjvBwllG9tpJvecs+PFXsZjfK3gTRMbEB4/yVw4QaqQcCL2zQsRYgJKNt7r3Vp3Jol6xhR/45FAntpFrJKio2Qwzmh4iQdAXvxZj/tR0e9c=
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="_000_AM9PR09MB45936DB89D92E97CAF50EBF2FB589AM9PR09MB4593eurp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_AM9PR09MB45936DB89D92E97CAF50EBF2FB589AM9PR09MB4593eurp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

sd

--_000_AM9PR09MB45936DB89D92E97CAF50EBF2FB589AM9PR09MB4593eurp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<style type="text/css" style="display:none;"> P {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;} </style>
</head>
<body dir="ltr">
<div style="font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
sd</div>
</body>
</html>

--_000_AM9PR09MB45936DB89D92E97CAF50EBF2FB589AM9PR09MB4593eurp_--
```

Comment: You are adding a mime attachment which starts with a new line with two dashes.  See following for sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: See the above suggested to see if it works. In addition you can access EWS Editor or MFCMAPI to see if it contains the x-headers or not as well.

Comment: I am not adding attachments. If I did, wouldn't the user see an attachment file in his client? Might the header be deleted by the outlook client when the mail is sent?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call [item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#getAllInternetHeadersAsync_options__callback_) to get internet headers on the current message in Read mode. This API will get all of the internet headers on the item, and you can filter the `asyncResult.value` for the header you are interested in.

Comment: I am trying to add a custom header.

Comment: Your custom header should have been set successfully based on your code snippet, but when you are trying to get the custom header while reading the mail, we would recommend to use item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync to get it instead of using Graph.

Comment: After setting, when you get the internetHeaders through Graph, are you getting it for the compose item still (the one you originally set the header on) or are you looking for those headers in the mail item received(read item) after the email is sent with the custom headers? If former, you won't see that header through graph. We promote properties to become internetHeaders after you've sent the item. They should be available on the read item received after sending the email when looking using Graph.